# Use Android MediaPlayer class to play a video from a URL

Tags: android, media-player

Can anyone tell me if the Android MediaPlayer class is able to play a video stored in a remote URL?

Just for testing purposes, can I use the URL `http://localhost/video-name.3gp`.

Answer (score 3):

> Can anyone tell me if the Android
>   MediaPlayer class is able to play a
>   video stored in a remoted URL?

Yes, if the video is [safe for streaming](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_frm/thread/f3ce21be6a10b50a/cc31b391e11e3c33?lnk=gst&q=moov#cc31b391e11e3c33).

> Just for testing purposes, can I use
>   the URL
>   http://localhost/video-name.3gp

No. localhost is going to be the emulator itself.

> Another question is if the MediaPlayer
>   works well on the emulator?

Only if you have a fairly fast machine, and not for streaming. You absolutely need hardware to test streaming video.

Comment: Could that be an openmoko device?

Comment: That would be a question for the OpenMoko developers.

Comment: Even regular video playback is a stretch in the emulator.  I've got a 3.06Ghz iMac with 8Gb of RAM, and video playback is about 5fps in the damn emulator.

Answer (score 0):

**Ans:- Yes**

create a media player object

```
Mediaplayer ob=mediaplayer.Create(mediaplayerActivity.this,file);
ob.start();
ob.play()
```